# M1 homebrew install with Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH

Tags: homebrew

I had issues when I `install Homebrew`,

> Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.

when I follow the instructions and run:

```
echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/Alex Lin/.bash_profile
```

It shows:

> -bash: /Users/Alex: Permission denied

Comment: Your home directory is not `/Users/Alex Lin` (and if it were, you'd need to quote or escape the space in it). Use `echo ~` to find out the correct path. Also, stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage or configuration; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) and [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) are better places to ask about things like this.